Determine if Processor is in Protected Mode using Mixed C and Assembly in Win OS
Research has revealed that machine status for 386+ processors is stored in the cr0 ( C, R, Zero ) register, and that the low bit being set will indicate protected mode is enabled.  The dirt-simple method is to copy cr0 into eax, and then in turn copy eax into a local C variable of the same size (32 bits).  We can then query the local C variable using the C language in any way we like.
Of course it fails, and hence this question. The failure is manifested as no output whatsoever, accompanied by a significant delay (maybe 2 secs) and then the program exits.  (No system crash).
Here is the code.  Please help me make it work: I expect output one way or the other: "IS" or "IS NOT" per the printf() statement. But no output occurs -- just a brief delay, and program exits. pushad+popad pair seemed a prudent add-on but made no difference.
OS: Windows 10.
Compilers:  VS 2022.  Borland C++ 5.5.1 for Win32.  Identical results for both compilers.
EDIT1: Perhaps the more exact question is:  What is the proper way to access register cr0?  -- because maybe the root cause is improper access?  Don't know!  Thanks community ...
EDIT2: This application targets legacy ms windows OSs that can swap between protected and real mode, all of which operate on processors >= 386. Both 16bit and 32bit code versions are anticipated, but 32 bit 1st and foremost.  Thanks again community for your participation and inquiries.
int is_prot_mode_cr0(void)
{
    unsigned long mstatus = 0;

    _asm {
        pushad
        mov eax, cr0;
        mov mstatus, eax;
        popad
    };
    return mstatus & 0x00000001;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Machine %s in Protected Mode.\n", is_prot_mode_cr0()?"IS":"IS NOT");
    _getch();
    return(0);
}


To be able to run the program, do you not already have to know the CPU mode?

I don't think you can read the cr* registers in user mode with mov. Try using smsw instead

mov eax, crX are privileged operations. Your program crashes because of that (2 second delay is a default crash dumper registering that crash; you should see that record in Event Viewer). The bigger question is why? This is a Windows program running under Windows; it is definitely in protected mode, there's no other choice.

@AndreyTurkin If it's a 16 bit program, it could run under Windows 3.0 standard mode.

smsw is the way to go but it will only return PE = 0 in Real 86 Mode vs = 1 in Virtual 86 Mode. smsw is not a privileged instruction. In an MSW 32-bit or 64-bit program you will never observe PE = 0.

One of the target systems for this code is Windows 98  -- which features a protected mode console when invoked from the GUI, or an "Exit to MS-DOS" feature which runs a console in real mode, plain text. This code is to confirm these modes for this OS and any other multi-mode OSs -- predominantly of that era.  The interest in authentic legacy hardware and software is due to a growing club of enthusiasts who are creating demand in unexpected ways, such as this code of mine
